# Does weak topology preserve topological vector space structure?

Tags: weak-convergence, topological-vector-spaces

Consider a topological vector space $X$ (not necessarily normed or metrisable or anything). Its topological dual is a well defined set of linear maps. With this in place, the weak topology is defined as the coarsest topology on $X$ such that all of the dual still consists only of continuous linear forms. It it possible that the weak topology be so coarse that $X$ equipped with its weak topology is no longer a topological vector space ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The weak topology that you speak about is *defined* by the seminorms (indexed by $f \in X^*$)

$$p_f : X \to [0, \infty), \ p_f (x) = |f(x)| .$$

In other words, a net $(x_i)_{i \in I}$ converges in this topology to $x$ if and only if

$$\lim \limits _{i \in I} |f (x_i) -f(x)| = 0 \; \forall f \in X^* .$$

This is the same topology as the one that you mention in your question, but describing it in terms of seminorms makes working with it much easier.

This topology is *necessarily* compatible with the algebraic structure of $X$, so the answer to your question is negative.

Comment: Before you responded, I had read that the weak topology was a topology on $X$. "Your" weak topology is on $X*$ isn't it ? Are they linked or homeomorphic or sthg ?

Comment: So if you equip a vector space with the coarsest topology that makes it a topological vector space, you actually get the weak topology then, no ? So why is it never defined that way ? Wouldn't it be easier to understand ?

Comment: @JamesWell: Some texts do define it the way I did, it's just a matter of stylistical preference. See more at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_topology.

Comment: @JamesWell: And no, the topology that I define is on $X$, I don't see why you concluded that it is on $X^*$.